# File "python", line 25 SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Tags: python

File "python", line 25
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

```
total=0
for key in prices:
    sum=prices[key]*stock[key]
    print sum
    total=total+sum
return total
```

Comment: This error is self-explanatory. You can't return a value without defining a function.

Answer (score 0):

Try relocating this code into a function.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
prices = { 'Python': 100 }
stock = { 'Python': 20 }

def total_portfolio_value():
  total=0
  for key in prices:
    sum=prices[key]*stock[key]
    print sum
    total=total+sum
  return total

total_portfolio_value()
```